# Error to get css in express

Tags: css, express, pug

I've been getting the error bellow when I try to reach http://localhost:3000/contato/1

```
GET http://localhost:3000/contato/static/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css 404 (Not Found)
```

Which is defined by this route:

```
app.route('/contato/:id')
    .get(autenticar, contatos.show);
```

In other routes that doesn't have :id param, the css is rendered fine.

I'm using Pug to develop the pages, and serving static files through public folder, using:

```
app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

My header.pug, which I extends in evey page.

```
doctype html
html
head
    link(href='static/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet')
    meta(charset='utf-8')
    meta(name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no")
    title Ntalk - Agenda de Contatos
body
    div(class='container')
        block content
```

The route who's getting the error:

show.pug

```
include ../header
  block content
    div(class='row')
      div(class='col-md-6 offset-md-3')
        section(class='container')
          header
            h2 Ntalk - Dados do contato
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the link to the css (*by adding / at the start*) in the **header.pug**

```
link(href='/static/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet')
```

Otherwise it is relevant to the current page